# Error while installing ionic capacitor printer plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, yarnpkg, capacitor

I am using this printer package with capacitor and I have installed it in my project. But when i try serve my ionic project its throwing an error of module not found

**https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer**

```
ERROR in /.../node_modules/@awesome-cordova-plugins/printer/ngx/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@awesome-cordova-plugins/core' in '/.../node_modules/@awesome-cordova-plugins/printer/ngx'
```

Comment: Have you installed @awesome-cordova-plugins/core ??

Comment: yes i have installed it can you please try to implement printer on your side and let me know if it works

Comment: @awesome-cordova-plugins/core  installing solved the issue i think it was a problem with cache once everything cleared and project rerun solved it

Comment: Glad to hear, happy coding.

Comment: @SaEChowdary https://stackoverflow.com/q/70663760/11999413 please chec this also

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure to install the core plugin before utilising,

```
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core --save
```